# uninstalling node.js doesnt remove bloatware components

Tags: node.js

just a quick question. I have installed nodejs and generated an application. After that I found that the hard disk performance degraded quite considerably. After uninstalling node js the node modules directory is still there! How do i get rid of this bloatware?

Comment: nodejs isn't bloatware.  Simply having nodejs on your hard drive doesn't do anything to slow down that hard drive unless something merely taking space on your hard drive causes such a problem in a malfunctioning system.  I'd suggest you fix your system so that putting some data on your hard drive doesn't slow down your system.  Also, what's wrong with just deleting the `node_modules` directory?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this question has been answered before:

[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177954/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-node-js-and-reinstall-from-beginning-mac-os-x)

To completely uninstall node + npm is to do the following:

The best answer stated:

1. go to /usr/local/lib and delete any node and node_modules
2. go to /usr/local/include and delete any node and node_modules directory
3. if you installed with brew install node, then run brew uninstall node in your terminal
4. check your Home directory for any local or lib or include folders, and delete any node or node_modules from there
5. go to /usr/local/bin and delete any node executable

Hope that helps!

Comment: Don't just add link, explain.

Comment: Where is the place to look for usr/local lib? I looked in C:\Windows, nothing comes up.